# VBA to update file properties

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table in my access database that contains an index of project files and their associated properties.  The fields include things like Filename, Filepath, Date Created, Date Modified, etc.

I'd like to create some code to loop through every record in this table and update file properties that may have changed - specifically, the date modified and file size.

The table is tblFileIndex and the relevant fields are File_Path, File_Size and Date_Modified.  The filepath is the full path, including file name, to the file so it seems to me it should be pretty easy to use that field to find the file and then update the file size and date modified.

I'm not sure how to go about creating the code to loop through the table and do this though.  I'd like the code to be assigned to a button on a form I have for maintenance functions as this will be run semi-frequently as part of a maintenance routine.

Below is some example code but I get Invalid use of Null errors from `sFilePath = rs.Fields("File_Path")` when it reaches the end of the record set.

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim sFilePath As String
Dim oFS As Object
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblFileIndex")

Do While Not rs.EOF
    sFilePath = rs.Fields("File_Path")
    MsgBox sFilePath
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

It looks like after I sort this out Ill need to add the following:

```
.Edit
rs.Fields("File_Size") = oFS.GetFile(sFilePath).Size
.Update
.Edit
rs.Fields("Date_Modified") = oFS.GetFile(sFilePath).DateLastModified
.Update
rs.MoveNext
```

Comment: AFAIK that `do while... loop` does not exist. Should be either `while not rs.EOF ... wend` or `do ... loop until rs.EOF`

Comment: Also, before the loop, go to the first row of the recordset: `rs.MoveFirst`

Comment: `Do While ... Loop` is valid VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's clean up things:

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim oFS As Object
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblFileIndex")
    with rs
        .moveFirst
        do
            sFilePath = .Fields("File_Path")
            .Edit
                .Fields("File_Size") = oFS.GetFile(sFilePath).Size
                .Fields("Date_Modified") = oFS.GetFile(sFilePath).DateLastModified
            .Update
            .moveNext
        loop until .EOF
        .Close ' Always close recordsets
    end with    
End Sub
```

---

Alternate notation for getting/setting `RecordSet` field values:

```
' ...
with rs
    .moveFirst
    do
        sFilePath = ![File_Path]
        .edit
            ![File_Size] = oFS.GetFile(sFilePath).Size
            ' ...
        .update
        .moveNext
    loop until .EOF
end with
' ...
end with
' ...
```

Comment: Works perfectly and helped make using recordsets in VBA a lot clearer for me, thanks for taking the time to clean it up.

Comment: @Bill Also take into consideration HansUp's answer... null values can be a pain in the neck

Answer (score 2):

*I get Invalid use of Null errors from sFilePath = rs.Fields("File_Path") when it reaches the end of the record set.*

Since your loop is controlled by `Do While Not rs.EOF`, that error suggests you have a row with Null in *File_Path*.

See whether that error goes away when you load the recordset with only rows where *File_Path* is not Null.

```vb
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "SELECT * FROM tblFileIndex WHERE File_Path Is Not Null;"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSelect)
```

Comment: Good catch, during my testing it must have created a blank record that I hadn't noticed along the way.

Comment: Maybe *File_Path* should never be Null?  If so, set Required = Yes for that field in table design.